# como regresar un rango en un array

Tags: array, java-swing

Una **función** recibe **tres parámetros:** inicio, final y paso. El parámetro inicio es el inicio del rango del array, final es el final del rango y paso es un valor que va aumentando el array que es devuelto por la función. *¿Cómo agrego el valor de paso para retornar el nuevo array?*

```
function rango(inicio, final, paso){
    let array = [];

    for(let i = inicio; i <= final; i++) {
        array.push(i);
   }

  return array;
}
   
console.log(rango(1, 10, 2)); // [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]    
console.log(rango(5, 2, -1)); // [5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function rango(inicio, final, paso)
{
   let array = [];

   if (paso > 0)
   {
      if (inicio <= final)
      {
         for (let i = inicio; i <= final; i += paso) 
         {
            array.push(i);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         console.log("El parámetro inicio debe ser menor que el parámetro final.");
      }
   }
   else if (paso < 0)
   {
      if (inicio >= final)
      {
         for (let i = inicio; i >= final; i += paso) 
         {
            array.push(i);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         console.log("El parámetro inicio debe ser mayor que el parámetro final.");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      console.log("El parámetro paso debe ser distinto a cero.");
   }

   return array;
}
```

Introduje varias validaciones a tu función:

Se pregunta si el **parámetro paso es positivo**, en caso de cumplirse esta condición se pregunta entonces si el **parámetro inicio** es menor o igual que el **parámetro final**, de cumplirse esta condición se ejecuta un **ciclo for**, de no cumplirse se muestra un mensaje de error por consola.

En caso de que el **parámetro paso sea negativo**, se pregunta entonces si el **parámetro inicio** es mayor o igual que el **parámetro final**, de cumplirse esta condición se ejecuta un **ciclo for**, de no cumplirse se muestra un mensaje de error por consola.

En caso de que el **parámetro paso sea igual a 0** se muestra un mensaje de error por consola.

Fíjate que en el **ciclo for** siempre se pone **i += paso**, ya que si el **parámetro paso** es positivo **la variable i** se incrementará, y si el **parámetro paso** es negativo la **variable i** se decrementará.

Por último se retorna el array con los valores que tenga de haberse cumplido correctamente las validaciones o un arreglo vacío en caso de no cumplirse las validaciones.

Comment: si el parámetro paso no se agrega, tendría que poner un if, para que realice el for sin considerar el valor paso en su iteración y quitar el else donde "El parámetro paso debe ser distinto de cero"?